# Setting entitlements on executables

Tags: macos, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I am developing a macOS program based on the C language. I created a macOS wrapper app called MyApp.app which is supposed to execute the program. I want to sandbox the program and to give it permission to access only certain resources.

This is how I codesign the program and the wrapper app:

```
codesign -s MyCert -f --keychain login.keychain --timestamp --options=runtime --deep --entitlements ents.plist myprogram

codesign -s MyCert -f --keychain login.keychain --timestamp --options=runtime --deep --entitlements ents.plist MyApp.app
```

Where `ents.plist` enables the `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` entitlement among others. The above commands don't report any errors. Then I check if sandboxing is really enabled on the app and it is on:

```
asctl sandbox check MyApp.app
/Users/Me/MyApp.app:
        signed with App Sandbox entitlements
```

As for the binary program, I get an error:

```
asctl sandbox check myprogram
asctl: unable to resolve path for application "myprogram"
```

If I run the program and check on the process, it gives me the following:

```
asctl sandbox check -p 16890
/Users/Me/myprogram:
        not signed with App Sandbox entitlements
        running without App Sandbox enabled
        running unsandboxed
```

How is sandboxing supposed to be enabled on binary executable programs?

Answer (score 3):

In order to enable the App Sandbox for command line utilities – I assume that this is what you try to achieve – you do not need a wrapper application / application bundle. What you need is the information property list (`Info.plist`), which is usually located inside such an application bundle. However, the `Info.plist` can be embedded into the binary, which allows you to enable sandboxing for the binary directly.

First, you need to create the missing `Info.plist` file.

The second step depends on whether you are using Xcode or another build system:

If you are using Xcode, select the `Info.plist` at the *Identity* section of the *General* tab of your target configuration. In the *Build Settings* tab, under section *Packaging*, you need to enable *Create Info.plist Section in Binary*. Now you can add the *App Sandbox* capability in the *Signing & Capabilities* tab.

If you are using another build system, make sure that you pass
`-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist /path/to/Info.plist` to the linker and embed the entitlements as described in the question – including the sandbox entitlement (`com.apple.security.app-sandbox`).

That's it – your command line utility should now be sandboxed.

In order to check whether the `Info.plist` is embedded correctly into the binary, you can display the embedded contents with the following sequence of commands:

```sh
objdump -m -section=__info_plist -s /path/to/binary | sed '1,/Contents of (/d'
```